# What is the best/preferred method for freeing a dynamic array of variants?

Tags: delphi, dynamic-arrays, variant

For instance, if I have the following:

```
type
  TVArray = array of array of Variant;
var
  MyArray : TVArray;
```

Then I add a bunch of elements to MyArray so that it has 1000 arrays of 30 variants each.

What is the best or preferred way to deallocate that memory if I want to do it right away?

```
MyArray := nil;
```

or

```
SetLength(MyArray, 0);
```

or

```
Finalize(MyArray);
```

or do I need to something to the sub arrays first?  Does it matter what the individual variants contain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All three are equivalent. Which you choose is a matter of style. I prefer the first one (assigning `nil`) because it's so succinct.

The compiler knows how to release `Variant` values. There's nothing additional you need to do before you release the array — if you bother to release the array at all, given that the compiler will destroy it for you eventually anyway.

Comment: If I may ask one additional question, are any of these three preferred if you also wish to port to FreePascal?

Answer (score 4):

Variants are managed types. This means that the compiler will take care of disposing of any resources associated with the variant when it goes out of scope. Treat the lifetime of variants just as you would treat strings, dynamic arrays, interfaces etc.

This means that all three variants are identical in meaning and correctly dispose of the array and its contents. You can choose to use whichever one you prefer.

Comment: Your answer and Rob's are nearly identical, so I gave the check to Rob since his was first.  Thank you, though.

Comment: @Jerry That's fine! I only added mine because Rob's original version didn't talk about disposing variants, i.e. the first paragraph to my answer. But he then covered that in an edit.